# How to return an ordered string from an unordered one?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to solve a problem but struggling with the logic approach to it. The problem is as follows:

"Your task is to sort a given string. Each word in the string will contain a single number. This number is the position the word should have in the result.

Note: Numbers can be from 1 to 9. So 1 will be the first word (not 0).

If the input string is empty, return an empty string. The words in the input String will only contain valid consecutive numbers."

For e.g. `"is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"  -->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"`

I have tried the following so far:

```
def order(sentence):
  my_string = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
  new_string = " "
  for i in my_string:
      if i in my_string == none
          return new_string = " "
      else:
          if i in my_string 
  return new_string
```

But stuck on continuing the next bit. How can I put "put words into order starting from 1" into python code into my for loop?

I'm a beginner in python and programming so I am not entirely sure if the approach I'm making is the best logical way to do so, by creating an empty string `new_string` and then sorting `my_string` into that. Is this a good way of approaching this? I am stuck on which direction to go after this.

Comment: `none` is not python - your whole code is garbage and does nothing towards solving your homework. Please follow some  [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to learn

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do :

```py
       r = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
       def get_number(w) :
          for x in w :
              try :
                  i = int(x)
                  return i
              except :
                  pass
          return None
       ordered_list = " ".join((sorted( s.split(' ') , key = get_number)))
```

the function `get_number` allows to get the first number appearing in a word, so we split the sentence to get the words it's made of , `r.split(' ')` gives `['is2', 'Thi1s', 'T4est', '3a']`, we order then the list using `ordered` builtin function , it takes a list and a function that yields the keys over which we want to order the list, and outputs the ordered list, we then use the builtin function `join` to join the list using a space separator.
Output :

```py
Out[425]: 'Thi1s is2 3a T4est'
```

Comment: Someone who wrote the code in the question is not going to understand this answer without (a lot of) explanation.

Comment: I edited my answer, I was kind of in a hurry when I wrote it the first time, I wish that's a bit clearer and that he(or she)  could understand it.